# Is there a way to change the windows phone 7 emulator orientation in runtime

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

Is there way to change the orientation of the emulator in runtime.

I have some tests for a component which include different layouts based on orientation. It would be great if this is possible.

Comment: 7 or 7.5 sdk? I believe the latter can.

Comment: 7.5 sdk with the latest update. (Not the beta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking for?

If you just want to change the orientation yourself, then use the mouse - there's some buttons top right on the emulator to change orientation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402568(v=VS.92).aspx

If you want to automate this, then since I'm not sure there's a keyboard shortcut or command line for this, then you could just about do it by modifying the code inside https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/

Alternatively... it might be quicker/easier to just hack your own code to set the supportedorientation of each page just for one-off testing.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about automate this. Maybe the idea to hack the supportedOrientation is a good choice. I'll try to see what will come up.

Answer (score 0):

Late response (translated by google), but can be useful for others.

Management guidance on this in the options bar to the right of the emulator:
Detail to know, so that the orientation is done properly and is taken into account, we must re-press the "pause" button if you did previously to use your keyboard. Otherwise, you will feel duty systematic tilt your head to the left or right. :)